# Reduction from planar bounded NCL to a static puzzle game

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, puzzles

I call `Fill3` the following simple game: the input is a $n \times n$ grid;

- every cell of the grid has a type: OR, AND, CHOICE, FANOUT and FIXED and can be rotated 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees;
- every cell (except the FIXED) contains three green squares that according to the cell's type can be placed in several different *valid configurations* (see figure);

The aim of the game is to choose a valid configuration for each cell (the type and the rotation cannot be changed) in such a way that no two green squares are adjacent (vertically or horizontally). The game is NP-complete (a quick reduction is from planar 3SAT).

[image]
Valid configurations for each type of cell.

But the cell types are obviously a direct transposition of the four gadgets used in the [bounded planar Nondetermnistic Constraint Logic (NCL)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.134.6525&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and the valid configurations match  the constraints of the corresponding vertices in a constraint graph (blue/red arrows in the figure).

I'm wondering if a direct quick reduction from NCL is possible. It is immediate to reduce a planar constraint graph to a `Fill3` game (CHOICE cells with a "free" endpoint can be used to build straight links and 90° turns). But in a bounded planar NCL problem $P$ the edges are reversed **dinamically** (though an edge can be reversed at most once) and the aim is to reverse a single edge; on the contrary the game `Fill3` is **static**. A possible approach is: build the corresponding `Fill3` game from $P$; "break" the edge that must be reversed (eventually expanding the board) and force it in the final direction using FIXED cells. Then one way is easy: if $P$ is solvable, the corrisponding `Fill3` game has a solution (represented by the final configuration of the constraint graph); but **the other way is more problematic**:

> If `Fill3` has a (static) solution $s$, can we say that a (dynamic) solution for the corresponding planar bounded NCL problem $P$ always exist (i.e. a sequence of valid edge reversals)? And how to prove it formally?

Comment: What is the difference between a blue arrow and a red arrow?

Comment: @TysonWilliams: the blue is a weight-2 edge, the red is a weight-1 edge in the corresponding NCL vertice. But in the NCL framework they are joined with a red-blue vertex with an inflow constraint of 1, so the final effect is that at least one of two edges must point "inward"; and this is the same behaviour that is achieved when we put two Fill3 cells side by side: if the two green blocks are adjacent (invalid configuration) then the corresponding directions in the juction are both "outward".